# I want to implement chrome manage password like functionality for C# MVC (client side technology javascript, jquery)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

Is there way to implement chrome manage password like functionality.

Where no one can see password value by inspect element.

To see a password it ask Windows credentials again, then only passsword is visible in text, that also no one can inspect.

I want to implement it for C# MVC5 application.

Please Guide.

Comment: Do you want to store the password in your application and not let anyone see the password? or do you want to make your browser offer to save password?

Comment: Yes we want to store the password in our application and not let anyone see the password